# Safely increment a field in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

I know there is a few posts on this already just wondering how secure it is to use

```
UPDATE table SET field = field + 1 WHERE [...]
```

What if the server lag out for a sec? Say 2 users click the page at the same time, will that cause them to both read the field as the same number and both increment that same field by 1? I'm guessing since it's mysql it has some sort of query system by doing one at a time but not sure if that is true, only assuming that's true.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this example the read and update are occurring in the same statement.  Statements are atomic (i.e. you can consider them to behave in a transactional way), so all's good.

Comment: I guess "atomic" was the word I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

The update statement is atomic.  When you run an update query the table (or row with innodb) is locked.  Period.  If two users click 'at the same time' it will correctly augment the field twice.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another method I use (if you have separate queries and don't want to unnecessarily lock the table):

Instead of updating, simply insert into another table (schema doesn't matter), count the items in that table regularly (not too often) and based on that update the other table. If the tables would grow to big, simple increment the count and then delete entries. Also lets you add other metadata, like a timestamp for further analysis.

Comment: This is for a voting system so it counts to 3 then resets and changes a few fields, so I don't think this need to get too technical.